# css pseudo class, hover on one element changes properties in different element

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I was wondering how I could set up css pseudo classes, specifically hover so when I hover over an element, like a div with an id, the properties of a different div with an id get changed?

so normally it would be this:

```css
#3dstack:hover {
  listed properties
}
```

I'm not sure what the change would be to have it hover on div with the id `3dstack` and have it change another div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think that is possible unless the element you want to change the properties of is a descendent or a sibling of the hovered element, in which case you can do:

```
#myElement:hover #myElementDescendent {
    background-color: blue;
}

/*or*/

#myElement:hover + #myElementSibling {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Of course you can always use jquery to do this:

```
$("#anelement").hover(
    function() {
        $("otherelement").css("background-color", "blue");
    });
```

[See the differences here](http://jsfiddle.net/AE3Ze/)

Comment: A child, a descendant, a sibling, or even a child/descendant of a sibling, or... you get the picture.

Comment: so the demo you made works, I'm trying to get this fiddle to work where you roll over and the opacity changes for in this case, a specific layer in the second containing div.  http://jsfiddle.net/7EH7X/  When I roll over it nothing seems to change, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here, the div I'm trying to change is a child and I as far as I can tell it's the same set up as what you did.  In the end for this I'd like to have all four of the children change on roll over.

Comment: It is probably a problem with your inline styles which cannot be overriden by pseudo-classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with CSS alone. You'll have to use a JavaScript event handler. For example, with jQuery's [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
​$('#3dstack').hover(function() {
    $('#otherID').toggleClass('properties');    
});​​​​​​​
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/xWZZr/)

Comment: so I tried what you did here http://jsfiddle.net/7EH7X/1/ and I wasn't able to get it to work, can you look at it quickly?

Answer (score 0):

*Visually* you can do this using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), but *under the hood* it's actually using JavaScript.